# Unable to apply wallpapers

Tags: gnome, bash, desktop-background, scripts

We are unable to apply wallpapers, we are getting the following error. How do i fix it??

**Error:**

```
Error setting value: Can't overwrite existing read-only value: Value 
for `/desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename' 
set in a read-only source at the front of your configuration path
```

**Output:**

```
# cat /etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory/%gconf-tree.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
<dir name="desktop">
    <dir name="gnome">
        <dir name="background">
            <entry name="picture_filename" mtime="1360589143" type="string">
                <stringvalue>/usr/share/backgrounds/time.jpg</stringvalue>
            </entry>
        </dir>
    </dir>
</dir>
```

**Note:**  Need Command line solution, coz i need to apply it for more than 300 hosts.

I am using 10.04 LTS. I am trying to apply wallpapers to all hosts remotely via SSH. I hope previously i have set the key to mandatory and so i am not able to set new wallpapers now. I need to apply new wallpapers now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `gconf-editor` (try even `sudo`, if needed) navigate to `/desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename` entry and select "**Clear the key**" option. Then, try again changing your wallpaper.

If this won't work, please provide your `/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory/%gconf-tree.xml` content.

**Edit**:

Reading just now you're trying setting the wp via ssh, set the mandatory key with:

```
# gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory --type string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "/path/to/your/image.jpg"
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0918/gconf-0/index.html

**To Set Background Preferences**

To set preferences for the desktop background, you modify the values of the preference keys in the /desktop/gnome/background location. For example, to set a mandatory image for the background, execute the following command:

```
# gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory --type string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename filename.png
```

To set a default value for this preference, execute the following command:

```
# gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --type string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename filename.png
```

You can also set other background preferences. For information about the other background preferences, see the desktop_gnome_background.schemas schema definition file.